# Laplacian Blur Detection Fails on Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, motion-blur

[image]

OpenCV newbie here. The result that I get after applying Laplacian filter for detecting blur as mentioned here https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/ and in various other sources is not good at all since the value is far too high to classify it as blurry.

Edit: My code

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
laplacian_var = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
```

result = 200.74997346028945

This might not seem really high but its higher than the other non blurry images I've tried this on.

Is there a better way to detect such kind of camera shake/ motion blur in images ?

Comment: All your images are of the same resolution?

Comment: No, but I resize them to a fixed size. Still the value is too high.